# Is it possible to wrap a mesh around another?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I am modeling a Nissan Z GT500 and I am wondering if it is possible to wrap a mesh on a curved object. I don't know how to explain so I try to show what I want to do with a picture:
[image]

Basically I want to wrap my Z mesh like on the balloon on left picture, not cutting into it but to be on the surface of it. When I tried shrinkwrap modifier it just got snapped on the surface but that is not what I want to do.

I hope I was clear, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Does your object have thickness? If not, actually the best way to do it is to integrate your letter into the balloon material. If it has thickness, give your letter a Surface Deform modifier, create a plane that will be the Target of this Surface Deform, and shrinkwrap the plane on the surface of the balloon. But of course your letter needs enough topology in order to be bent

Comment: Thank you moonboots the latter worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your object have thickness? If not, actually the best way to do it is to integrate your letter into the balloon material.

If it has thickness, give your letter a *Surface Deform* modifier, create a plane that will be the *Target* of this *Surface Deform*, and shrinkwrap the plane on the surface of the balloon, your letter will deform accordingly. But of course your letter needs enough topology in order to be bent.